# Any way to inspect iCloud Key-Value store?

Tags: ios, ios8, icloud, key-value-store

I'd like to see the Key-Value store data in the cloud to see if a given sync worked out. It would be also great to change the values in the cloud to see them syncing. Any tool for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can see all iCloud containers syncing at the moment and their location.

```
open ~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.syncedpreferences.plist
```

Each container has `plistPath` key with path to another plist file actually with current key value data. Example:

```
/Users/<user>/Library/Containers/<app-bundle-name>/Data/Library/SyncedPreferences/<app-bundle-name>.plist
```